# how to update recyclerview after pulling data from server?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

If i had to send a request to get data within `onBindViewHolder()`, how can i update view after data comes back from server?

what I have now is that I cache the data along with row position, so that next time when user scrolls to that row, I can display info right away.

but there are 2 other issues I don't know how to solve.

1. I scroll the list to view item at position 10, 11 and 12. I decided to wait for data to come back. do i call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after? because `onBindViewHolder` already been called by the time data comes back and view would just remained empty, but I also don't think by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` after each request would be a good idea.
2. I start to view the list at position 0 and keep scrolling to position 10. app sends out request to pull data for position 0 to 10. since the request at 0 is sent out first, more likely it would get back first or at least sooner than position 10, but by that time I'm already viewing the item at position 10. my view would start changing if all requests are back in order, so it would show data for position 0 then keep updating all the way to 10.

is it a bad practice to load data from server as `recyclerview` scrolls? but by doing this would save me a lot of time, and I guess for user too? because instead of sending all the requests ahead of time, user get to see partial data while other data are being loaded in the background.

Thanks!!!

**EDITED**

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context ctx;
    private ArrayList<Photo> alPhotos = new ArrayList<>();
    private HashMap<String, Drawable> hmImages = new HashMap<>();

    public TestAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Photo> alPhotos) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.alPhotos = alPhotos;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_photo_brief, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Photo photo = alPhotos.get(position);

        loadRemoteImage(photo.IMG, holder.ivThumb, true);
        holder.tvEmail.setText(photo.EMAIL);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return alPhotos.size();
    }

    private void loadRemoteImage(final String imgUrl, final ImageView view, final boolean cache) {
        if (hmImages.containsKey(imgUrl)) {
            view.setImageDrawable(hmImages.get(imgUrl));
        } else {
            final WeakReference<ImageView> weakView = new WeakReference<>(view);
            RequestManager.getManager().add(new Request<>(imgUrl, new DrawableParser(), new RequestCallback<Drawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFinished(Request<Drawable> request, Response<Drawable> response) {
                            if (cache) hmImages.put(imgUrl, response.result);

                            ImageView view = weakView.get();
                            if (view != null) {
                                view.setImageDrawable(response.result);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Request<Drawable> request, Response<Drawable> response) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeout(Request<Drawable> request, Response<Drawable> response) {
                        }
                    })
            );
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView ivThumb;
        private TextView tvEmail;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            findViews();
        }

        private void findViews() {
            ivThumb = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivThumb);
            tvEmail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: update your data like the arraylist

Comment: but view is updated inside of `onBindViewHolder`. even though data set is updated, `onBindViewHolder` isnt being called again.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea to load data while scrolling, a lot of popular apps do that. I personally use `WeakReference` in this case. I store a weak reference to the view holder in my model when I start loading data. If the reference is still valid by the time I get the response then it makes sense to update the view. If there is no view holder in memory then it's already been recycled and I don't have to update anything anymore.

When `onViewRecycled` is called you can clear the weak reference and also consider cancelling the network request (depends on your needs).

Caching works perfect with this model, you just insert this logic before making a network request. Again, this depends on your needs, maybe you don't need caching at all, or maybe your data is rarely updated then it makes sense to always use cache until some event.

In my app I also use EventBus, it helps me with event handling, but it is absolutely fine to just use Android SDK and support library.

You can also add a `ScrollListener` if you need to differentiate the item behavior depending on whether user scrolls the list right now. E.g. in my app I animate the data if list loaded and user wasn't scrolling it (improves interaction with the user). When user scrolls I load data as is, because it will be too much motion on the screen if I animate data.

Comment: sounds promising. i've never used or heard `WeakReference`. guess its google time now

Comment: `WeakReference` helps to prevent a memory leak. You don't want your network request to prevent GC from collecting an unused `View` which will happen if you hold a strong reference.

Comment: do u have an example? from what I just googled, its simple as changing from `ImageView` to `WeakReference<ImageView>`, but I still see my view gets updated few times before it really shows the correct one. (meaning it still shows data for position 0 to 10)

Comment: No, sorry, there is too much code to post here as an example.. The issue is in your view updating logic, not in `WeakReference` itself. `WeakReference<ViewHolder>` just prevents memory leaks, it won't fix your problem with showing wrong data. Please share your adapter code.

Comment: Hi @Gennadii Saprykin, I've posted my adapter. can you please tell me what i did wrong? this issue has been bothering me. thank you!!!

Comment: Views are reused while you scroll, i.e. you will see previous images being reused. To fix this you need to show a placeholder before you load an image. This will reset reused image view state.

Comment: even after I set a default image, I'm still seeing images being shown from previous rows. images are updated few times before it shows the correct one

Comment: I think this happens because old requests keep updating your views. You need to tell them that you no longer need the response. `RecyclerView` has a method `onViewRecycled`. Tell your model to clear the weak reference when this method is called. This way you will not update the view for old items, just store data in cache. You will need to refactor your code a little bit, because currently you don't store your weak reference anywhere. It should be accessible from `onViewRecycled` to actually tell the adapter what view to recycle.

Comment: weird...im still seeing the issue. i assign the request to `holder` then get the weak reference from request and clear it in `onViewRecycled`.

Comment: seems a lit better. instead of updating 10 images until the correct one, it now updates only 3-5 images. just so weird....

Comment: humm... i dont get it now. from what I understand now, wrapping `ImageView` to `WeakReference` is to rely on GC clear unused view, so when doing the check `if (view != null)` should be good enough

Comment: No, wrapping to `WeakReference` makes it possible for GC to clear the view if needed. You still need to clear it manually when `onViewRecycled` is called to avoid multiple image updates from old requests.

Comment: i see. that's what I'm doing now, and i can see it performs better then before. i think what it does now is that instead of updating images from position 0 all the way to 10. it now updates from 7 to 10 because some views are not recycled yet thus not passed to `onViewRecycled`.